# Ionic Switching States with $state.go

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm very new to Ionic and HTML/JS, but I'm trying to develop a basic app with 4 views, switching between them with $state.go. The first view contains a button, and when it is clicked, it should switch to the second state, but it does not. Any suggestions of how to correct this are greatly appreciated.

My app.js and index.html are below.

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var quiz = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: '/',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })
    .state('page1', {
      url: "/page1",
      params: {
        'imageQuestionAnswer':null,
        'textQuestionAnswer':null
      },
      controller: 'page1Ctrl'
    })
    .state('imageQuestion', {
      url: "/imageQuestion",
      params: {
        'imageQuestionAnswer':null,
        'textQuestionAnswer':null
      },
      controller: 'pictureQCtrl'
    })
    .state('textQuestion', {
      url: "/textQuestion",
      params: {
        'imageQuestionAnswer':null,
        'textQuestionAnswer':null
      },
      controller: 'textQCtrl'
    })
    .state('result', {
      url: "/result",
      params: {
        'imageQuestionAnswer':null,
        'textQuestionAnswer':null
      },
      controller: 'resultCtrl'
    })
})

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("index.html")


quiz.controller("page1Ctrl", function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $state) {

  $scope.onStart = function() {
    $state.go("imageQuestion", {
      'imageQuestionAnswer':null,
      'textQuestionAnswer':null
    })
  }

})

quiz.controller("pictureQCtrl", function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $state) {

})

quiz.controller("textQCtrl", function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $state) {

})

quiz.controller("resultCtrl", function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $state) {

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='quiz'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Welcome to my quiz app!</title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>


  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  <ion-content>
    <ion-view view-title="Welcome!">
    <ion-content class = "padding">
      <div>
        <button class = "button button-royal" ng-click = "onStart()">Start</button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
  </ion-content>

  <script id = "imageQuestion" type="text/ng-template">
   <div>
     Question 2!
   </div>
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling onSubmit() function but in controller you have declared the function name $scope.onStart. change the function name , it would work.

Comment: I have made this correction and edited the above code, but still have the same issue.

Comment: you have made another mistake that is you are defining your module as 'starter' in app.js and injecting the unknown module 'quiz' in index.html.

change this line 
    `var quiz = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])`
to 
     `var quiz = angular.module('quiz', ['ionic'])`

Comment: You should also correct your routes and html should not be in index.html. Create separate views for each of your controller. Refer to the documentation/tutorial to learn the basics of ionic app.